# how duplicate a oh-my-zsh terminal and retaining the path from previous terminal

Tags: 14.04, zsh

In shell zsh command line/terminal when i duplicate the terminal using Ctrl+ Shift + T , it doesn't retain the path i was on my previous terminal.

Also `Ctrl+Shift+N` opens a fresh terminal. Though this works in bash but not in zsh.

Is it possible to duplicate terminal with path retaining from previous terminal .I am using oh-my-zsh with zsh

zsh-version : 5.0.2
ubuntu version : 14.04

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in the .zshrc file:

```
[[ -f /etc/profile.d/vte.sh ]] && . /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1132700

Comment: can you explain a bit about these commands. thanks

Comment: Part in the command "[[ -f /path/to/file ]]" means check if the file exist and if is it true, execute the file. Space between . and / means execute the script in the current shell.